# Executing a Do File in Mac Stata SE 16.1

Tags: stata

I have a .do file in Stata SE 16.1 on Mac OSX and I'm looking to execute it. I'm traditionally a Windows user, so am used to executing using control-D. When I attempt to do the same on the Mac OSX, a small Finder window pops up and forces me to choose which file I want to execute. Is there a way to get rid of this? I just want to be able to mouse-less way of executing the currently open .do file...

Comment: If there is a 'Do' menu select that without letting go of the mouse - if there is a menu command it will show up there - it's likely to be command D. Check under Stata -> Quit to see the 'Command Q' for an example.

Comment: https://www.stata.com/manuals/gsm.pdf Ch.13 may help.

Comment: https://www.stata.com/manuals/u.pdf 16.3.2 Creating and running do-files for Mac

Comment: Checkout http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/ if you find you want to create your own shortcuts for Stata

Answer (score 4):

Shift-Command-D is the default Mac OS keystroke to execute the .do file in the currently active window. This will also execute selections, and is equivalent to Window Cntrl-D.

The comments above are all true as well.

Comment: Thank you Arthur! This is exactly the answer I was looking for.